# Create extension on String?

Tags: swift3

I want to trimm the white space from the input field value.Input field value might be null so instead of applying if let for all field I want to create extension on String?. How to create extension on String? in swift3 ?

Comment: Do you mean on `String?`, like `Optional<String>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for an extension on `String?` (a.k.a. `Optional<String>`), then you can do something like this:

```
import Foundation

// From @ArpitDongre
extension String{
    func trimmed() -> String {
       return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func trimmed() -> String? {
        return self?.trimmed()
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to create an extension to write `string.trimmed()` instead of `string?.trimmed()` :)

Comment: @Sulthan It doesn't xD But this is a nice way of demonstrating extensions on generic types with concrete generic parameters

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
extension String{

    func trimmed() -> String{
       return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
"abcd  ".trimmed()
```

*or*

```
let text = "abcd  "
text.trimmed()
```

Comment: You should name it `trimmed()`. `trim()` should be the `mutating` version.